# Java generic return generic list of type of parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to create the following:

```
//infer the type from parameter but restrict it to one of
// Proxy's subtype. return a list of this sub type
public static List<T> process(<T extends Proxy> proxy)
{
  return new ArrayList<T>(); //just for example
}
```

Usage:

```
List<ConcreteTypeOfProxy> list = process(new ConcreteTypeOfProxy());
```

The above example has compilation issues. I think this should logically be available in java, just not sure what the syntax is

Comment: Should be `public static <T extends Proxy> List<T> process(T proxy)`

Comment: Ok. I've to add type restriction before the return type. Got it thanks.

Comment: But note that the above won't work for your `List<ConcreteTypeOfProxy> list = process(new SubscriberProxy())` usage (because `T` must be the same for return List type and method argument). So it should be `List<ConcreteTypeOfProxy> list = process(new ConcreteTypeOfProxy());` (or both must be `SubscriberProxy`)

Answer (score 4):

```
//Any array that extends T
public static  <T extends Proxy> List<T>  process(T proxy)
{
    return new ArrayList<T>(); //just for example
}

//Returns array that has T type of parameter
public static  <T> List<T>  process(T proxy)
{
    return new ArrayList<T>(); //just for example
}

//Returns a map of generic type which you define in the method
public static <T, E extends Proxy> Map<T, E>  process(T key, E value)
{
    Map<T, E> map =  new HashMap<T, E>();
    map.put(key, value);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but since ernest answered first gotta give it to him :)

Comment: yes I agree actually I haven't seen the comments, I was just typing the code in IDE before posting it here. :)

Comment: It's not clear to me why this is any better than just using `new ArrayList<>()` directly.

Comment: I have added and Example for map also

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any method, and consequently you don't need any parameters, to do this:

```
List<ConcreteTypeOfProxy> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Remember: there is no difference between `ArrayList<ConcreteTypeOfProxy>` and `ArrayList<AnyOtherType>`: it's just an `ArrayList`.

The type parameter is merely an instruction to the compiler to check the type of what is added - at compile time only - and to automatically cast values obtained from the list.

Comment: I know that's why I've mentioned what i am doing within the method as just an example. This is going to be exposed as an api and I'll be doing additional work within the method. :)